# pari/gp "bnfisintnorm" as poor man (quadratic) Thue equations solver?

Tags: diophantine-equations, number-fields, mathematical-software

For simplicity explaining only the quadratic case.

Given integers $n,m$, pari/gp "bnfisintnorm" finds $X,Y$
such that $X^2+n Y^2=m$ working in the number field
with defining polynomial $x^2+n$ and needs to call
initialization of the number field.

This continue work correctly when we declare $n$ as prime
while it is composite and requires factoring of only $m$.
Initializing the number field is very slow experimentally.

If necessary assume $n$ is positive, since $n<0,m=1$
is computing the fundamental units.

When solving $a x^2+b y^2=c z^2$, in general the factorizations
of $a,b,c$ are necessary according to papers.

> Q1 How comes the factorization of $n$ is not needed?
>
> Q2 What is the minimal information for the number field
> for this to work.

pari/gp session:

```
p=nextprime(2^40);q=nextprime(p+1);n=p*q;addprimes(n);K=bnfinit(x^2+n)
? bnfisintnorm(K,2^2+n)
%10 = [-x - 2, -x + 2]
```

Comment: A guess would be that if you declare $n$ to be prime while it is not, you may get incorrect results. Also note that pari/gp has a Thue equation solver.

Comment: Could the title be improved to something less cryptic?

Comment: @Aurel Could be, but experimentally so far the results are correct.

Comment: @Aurel pari's Thue equation solver also appears to work with declaring $n$ prime.

Comment: @joro It might be complicated to construct an example where pari actually fails, because in Thue-type of problem the hardest part is usually to prove that there is no other solution than the obvious ones. But let me also argue that if you only tried $n$ squarefree, then the output *should* be correct: indeed in this case pari will correctly compute a maximal order (see documentation of nfinit for more details) and the rest of the computation will therefore be correct. To obtain a counterexample I would try $n=p^2q$ for large primes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Note also that bnfisintnorm (as a number of other gp/pari functions) is only guarenteed to work correctly if one assumes GRH!

Comment: Quite from the manual: "Warning. Make sure you understand the above! By default, most of the bnf routines depend on the correctness of the GRH. In particular, any of the class number, class group structure, class group generators, regulator and fundamental units may be wrong, independently of each other. Any result computed from such a bnf may be wrong. The only guarantee is that the units given generate a subgroup of finite index in the full unit group. You must use bnfcertify to certify the computations unconditionally."

Comment: @KasperAndersen I don't mind assuming GRH, but the running time is dominated by |bnfinit| and I am trying to decrease it.

Comment: @Aurel I am mainly trying to minimize or avoid |bnfinit| and don't mind some failures in the computation.

Comment: If you declare $n$ to be prime, you don't really decrease the running time of bnfinit, you only decrease the running time of nfinit that is called first. You can use the combination nfinit/nfcertify by using the extra parameters of nfinit to avoid part of the expensive factorisation, and then call bnfinit(nf). If you have specific examples that take too long, try running in debug mode (\g k) for some k>0 to see which part of the computation is taking long.